# Sampling distributions: CLT, t-distribution

Tags: sampling, central-limit-theorem

Here is my understanding:

1. If you have **any** distribution, mean unknown but variance known, the sampling distribution of the mean is normally distributed if $n$ is large, and this normal distribution has the mean of the population the samples came from, and variance $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ (where $\sigma$ is the variance of the population).

2. If you have a **normal** distribution but you do not know the mean and variance, the sampling distribution of the mean will be a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom

My question is first, are the above points correct?

Second, what happens in the case where you are sampling from any distribution, not necessarily normal, and you do not know the mean or variance? Would the sampling distribution not follow a normal distribution $N\sim (\mu,\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}})$, where $s=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})$?

Comment: On the right track, but more precise statements are needed. See my answer.

Comment: @fmtcs   The CLT is about the distribution of standardized sample means (or sums) *in the limit* as n goes to infinity, under certain conditions. If you have joint normality then the distribution of sample means is *normal*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your #1, you need to say that the sampling distribution of $\bar X$ is **approximately normal.**

How large a sample is large enough for a *good* approximation depends on the shape of the population distribution. For uniform data, $n=20$ works well; for an exponential population distribution, $n=200$ may work OK, but $n = 20$ is not enough.

Illustrative simulations in R:

```
set.seed(1212)
a.unif = replicate(10^5, mean(runif(20)))
summary(a.unif);  sd(a.unif)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2223  0.4558  0.4997  0.4998  0.5439  0.7524 
[1] 0.06458699

a.ex20 = replicate(10^5, mean(resp(20)))
summary(a.ex20);  sd(a.ex20)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.3244  0.8408  0.9826  0.9988  1.1390  2.2612 
0.2224916

a.ex200 = replicate(10^5, mean(rexp(200)))
summary(a.ex200);  sd(a.ex200)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.7353  0.9515  0.9984  1.0000  1.0467  1.3386 
[1] 0.07083102
```

The figure below shows that $n = 20$ is not large enough
to give a nearly normal distribution for the average of exponential data.

[image]

R code for above figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 hdr1 = "n=20, UNIF(0.1): Sample Means; Normal Fit"
  hist(a.unif,  prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main=hdr1)
   curve(dnorm(x, mean(a.unif), sd(a.unif)), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
  hdr2 = "n=20, EXP(1): Sample Means; Normal Fit"
  hist(a.ex20,  prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main=hdr2)
   curve(dnorm(x, mean(a.ex20), sd(a.ex20)), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
  hdr3 = "n=200, UNIF(0.1): Sample Means; Normal Fit"
  hist(a.ex200,  prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main=hdr1)
   curve(dnorm(x, mean(a.ex200), sd(a.ex200)), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

---

It is the same story for your last paragraph, but then also $S/\sqrt{n}$ is only an *approximate* standard deviation based on your sample of size $n.$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm still a bit confused about my last paragraph. If we can use $s/ \sqrt{n}$ for the standard error in the case where we don't know anything about the original distribution, why then do we get a t-distribution if we know the original distribution is normal but don't know the parameters? In that case couldn't we just say the sampling means are distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $s/ \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: If data are normal, then $T = \frac{\bar X-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu = n-1).$ But for normal data $\bar X$ and $S$ are stochastically independent, so if data aren't normal it isn't quite enough for $\bar X$ to be essentially normal, in order for the T-statistic to truly have a t dist'n. // Maybe it would help if you can explain your interests/purposes in your last paragraph, which seems to be some combination of wrong and confusing.